# How to connect Kafka (Java) application from Windows to Confluent in Linux

Tags: java, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm running Confluent 5.0 in Linux server using Winscp and Putty. I have Kafka (Java/Eclipse) application in Windows.

When I run Java application, its not identifying Kafka brokers in Confluent running on Linux.

I have tested my Java application which send data to Kafka topics in MACBook, by running Confluent 5.0 in MAC Terminal. Now I am trying to implement same Kafka application in Windows. Since Confluent is not supported in Windows, I'm running in Linux server.

I'm using Confluent instead of Apache Kafka because I'm using Schema-registry in my application.

By using netstat -tupln & curl -v http:/localhost:port no. figured out Kafka's running on 8082 and schema registry on 8081 [details of ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptPm1.png).
Below is my Kafka Properties in Java application.

```
public static Properties producerProperties() {

    // normal producer
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:8082");
    properties.setProperty("acks", "all");
    properties.setProperty("retries", "10");
    // avro part
    properties.setProperty("key.serializer", StringSerializer .class.getName());
    properties.setProperty("value.serializer", KafkaAvroSerializer .class.getName());
    properties.setProperty("schema.registry.url", "http://127.0.0.1:8081");

    return properties;

}

public static Properties consumerProperties() {

   // Properties properties = new Properties();
    // normal consumer
    properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:8082");
    //different for consumer
    properties.setProperty("group.id", "Avro-consumer");
    properties.setProperty("enable.auto.commit", "false");
    properties.setProperty("auto.offset.reset", "earliest");

    // avro part
    properties.setProperty("key.deserializer", StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    properties.setProperty("value.deserializer", KafkaAvroDeserializer.class.getName());
    properties.setProperty("schema.registry.url", "http://127.0.0.1:8081");
    properties.setProperty("specific.avro.reader", "true");

    return properties;
}

public static Properties streamsProperties() {

    // normal consumer
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "com.github.ptn006");
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:8082");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");

    properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
    properties.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());

    return properties;
}
```

Expected:
Data written to Kafka topics.

Actual:
WARN Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient:589)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that [`advertised.listeners` of the `server.properties` file in Kafka is resolvable](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/) by the Windows machine. Also ensure the firewall is allowing access (`netstat -tupln | grep LIST`), and look for your Kafka port listening on `0.0.0.0`, for example.

Comment: updated my post with details of ports from linux and kafka prop's in java code. please let me know if I'm missing anything else.

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is your Windows machine, not the linux one

Comment: Thank you!! By pointing linux server address and port number, it worked fine!